# How do I override JSON errors and prevent a blank page from loading?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How do I prevent my JSON feed from crashing and ignore errors from a database if they occur while running, also how do I change the undefined errors into a string to return as a fall back like "pending" or "not available."

I tried inputting the Try, catch, finally method. Also, the If statements conditional equal and null ones I found to change undefined into a "string"

```
var flight             = document.getElementById("flight");
var time               = document.getElementById("time");
var airline            = document.getElementById("airline");
var stat               = document.getElementById("status");
var cities             = document.getElementById("cities");

//Loading the document



//this is for updating the url
 var url                = './airport-test.json';
//var url = './proxy.php';
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "json",
 url: url,
 async: true,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 cache: false,
 success: function (data) {
 var flightString      = "";
 var timeString        = "";
 var airlineString     = "";
 var statString        = "";
 var citiesString      = "";

 if(data) {
      try {
        var a           = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(a);
        } catch(e) {
       var errorMessage = e.name + '' + e.message;
       console.log(errorMessage);
      }
    }


  for (i= 0,l = data.length = 16; i < l; i++ ) {
 code here I erased to fit this question better...

     }




 flight.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', flightString);
 time.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', timeString);
 airline.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', airlineString);
 stat.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', statString);
 cities.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', citiesString);

      }});

    });
```

I am using a raspberry pi with chromium I just want the JSON feed to still show up even when there is an error instead of a blank page. It works most of the time. Also, want to change undefined from errors into a fallback string.

Comment: similar to `success` you can define `error` handler.

Comment: How do I define the error handler properly?

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what exactly is the problem, taking a wild guess the server is not responding properly.

Define error handler,

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "json",
 url: url,
 async: true,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 cache: false,
 success: function (data) {
  ....
 }
 error: function (error) {
  // handle your error here.
  ....
 }
```